# wildfly10 and slf4j and logback do not work

Tags: logback, slf4j, wildfly-10

I followed the following configuration for wildfly10:
https://developer.jboss.org/thread/237094

So to be able to use slf4j and logback in my application I disabled the logging subsystem:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>  
  <deployment>  
     <!-- exclude-subsystem prevents a subsystems deployment unit processors running on a deployment -->  
     <!-- which gives basically the same effect as removing the subsystem, but it only affects single deployment -->  
     <exclude-subsystems>  
        <subsystem name="logging" />  
    </exclude-subsystems>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

With this configuration my application uses correctly my logback configuration: the problem is that the server does not use anymore its own logging, so the general information are not written anymore to server.log, but they are written to my application appender.

This sounds very strange to me: I tried a lot of other configurations like excluding directly the modules (i.e. `org.slf4j` and `org.slf4j.impl`) on my `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file but with no effect.

Comment: Are you saying logs from WildFly itself are going in to your logback configured appenders?

Comment: Yes, correct. All the logging statements that usually are on server.log are redirected on my logback appender.

Comment: That seems odd since the server loggers should not even see logback. Is anything going into the server.log at all?

Comment: Nothing goes into server.log, when I deploy my app simply jboss stops writing on server.log. My application is a spring boot based application that bring slf4j and logback dependency by its own.

Comment: I don't know much about Spring Boot, but maybe it's clearing the handlers from the log manager. I can't think of any other reason logging would just stop working.